# Как спрятать actionbar у Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать ActionBar у Диалога выделенное красным цветом?

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.block);
                dialog.show();
```

---

При использовании

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.block);
                dialog.show();
```

получаю такое чудо. Почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.block);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Спс конечно, но это немного не то. Скинул картинку. Гляньте выше что я получил.....

Comment: @xTIGRx  добавьте `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` перед `dialog.show();`

Comment: Спс Бро!)  .....